# Change sale module view, treestrings, names, button names

Tags: python, xml, xpath, view, odoo

I need to change for instance in the `treeview` of `openerp's` `sale` module, just the `tree strings` of `quotation` and `sale order`

To accomplish this, i'm making a brand new module (*init* _openerp_ and view.xml files)

I will inherit the `view` and then override name with `xpath` problem is, i still can't accomplish it, it is giving me an

```
ERROR:RELAXNGV:RELAXNG_ERR_ELEMWRONG: Did not expect element record there
```

My code is:

```
<record id="view_quotation_tree" model="ir.ui.view" >
<field name="name">sale.order.tree.inherit</field>
<field name="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
 <xpath expr="//tree[@string='Quotation']" position="replace">
    <tree string="Servicios" fonts="bold:message_unread==True" colors="grey:state=='cancel';blue:state in ('waiting_date','manual');red:state in ('invoice_except','shipping_except')">
    </tree>
 </xpath>
</field>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I need to change for example, the title `Quotation` for `Solicitud de Servicios`, or `Sale Order` to `Compra de Servicios`.

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
<record id="view_quotation_tree" model="ir.ui.view" >
<field name="name">sale.order.tree.inherit</field>
<field name="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
 <xpath expr="//tree[@string='Quotation']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="string">Servicios</attribute>
</xpath>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace the tree.try position='attributes'

```
<xpath expr="/tree[@string='Quotation']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="string">Servicios</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Thank you both but it says 'AttributeError: View definition error for inherited view '' on model 'sale.order': Element '<xpath expr="//tree[@string='Quotation']">' not found in parent view 'sale.view_quotation_tree'' It actually appears there =/